# Dialogflow Messenger Integration - Add a chat-icon

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to change the dialogflow default icon in the web integration using the "Dialogflow Messenger" integration option.

I added the "chat-icon" tag to the "df-messenger" tag and it's not showing the custom logo.

[Image of the web integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8sDI.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the image link you are using is publicly accessible? As you said, you just need to set this on your embed:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger
  chat-icon="<a valid and public link here>"
  intent="WELCOME"
  chat-title="<your chatbot title here>"
  agent-id="<your agent id here>"
  language-code="pt-br"
></df-messenger>
```

Maybe you could try using another random image first (ie. a link from google images) just checking if it works and then troubleshooting with your custom image?

Comment: I uploaded the image in the imgur website. I think it is public.
https://i.imgur.com/GRdD4cW.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making the icon exactly 36x36 px as written in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger

I uploaded it to Firebase and got the public link, it works.
Hope it helps!